# Enabling Access 2010 macros via Group Policy (SBS 2003)

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, microsoft-office-2010

We get an error message every time staff open one of our database applications, due to the default settings in Access 2010 of prompting for approval every time a macro is run: "*Disable all macros with notification*".

[image]

Is there any way, via Group Policy on SBS 2003, to enable macros for Access 2010 when the user logs on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "Enable all Macros" option for the "VBA Macro Notification Settings" GP setting in the Access 2010 Group Policy template. You'll need to download the Office 2010 GP templates and add the Access 2010 template to a GPO.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18968

[image]

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen: I believe we have a winner.